# Explain how left shift works in Java

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

Why does the following program code output the value -32 to the console?

```
int num = 0xFFFFFFE;
for(int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
  num = num << 1;
  System.out.println(num);
}
```

The program produces the following result:

```
536870908
1073741816
2147483632
-32
```

I know that when the binary digit is shifted to the highest (31st) position, the value becomes negative.

I can't quite figure out why -32. Why not -16 or -8, namely the result is -32?

I would be glad if you could explain this to me in more detail. If you can accompany the answer with images, it will be just great.

I hope my question is not stupid.

Comment: Since you already know it's about binary digits (also know as bits), have you looked at these five numbers (`0xFFFFFFE`, `536870908`, `1073741816`, `2147483632`, `-32`) in binary?

Comment: HINT: `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-1));`

Comment: I got the hint. The results are written below in binary form:
1) 11111111111111111111111111100        (536870908)
2) 111111111111111111111111111000      (1073741816)
3) 1111111111111111111111111110000    (2147483632)
4) 11111111111111111111111111100000  (-32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have to do with the bit shiting as such. Java uses [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent negative numbers and the last shift makes `num` contain

```java
0xFFFFFFE0 // 11111111111111111111111111100000 in binary representation
```

which is -32 using two's complement. You can remove the bitshifts and observe the same output:

```java
int num = 0xFFFFFFE0;
System.out.println(num); // -32
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(num));
```

Comment: That is, it is important for me to remember the following: "The two's complement principle divides all binary representations into two sets: if the leftmost bit is 0, then the number is positive, if 1, then the number is negative." ???

Ted, are there any other points that I need to pay attention to?

Comment: @MAGistr Yes, that point is good to remember, but it's just the beginning of what two's complement is and that part is actually the same for [ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement).